# Not removing class or adding class

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to make a star rating system, and I managed to make it so you can make the stars yellow.  When I click the stars again, they don't turn white.  In other words, I need help toggling the stars so they change colors.  I'm a beginner in html, so I don't know what the problem is.  Any help would be appreciated!  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Star Rating</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".n").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'star_checked.png');
        $(this).removeClass("n");
        $(this).addClass("y");
      });
      $(".y").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'star.png');
        $(this).removeClass("y");
        $(this).addClass("n");
      });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
      div#rating {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="stars">
      <img class="y" src="star_checked.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <img class="y" src="star_checked.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <img class="n" src="star.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <img class="n" src="star.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <img class="n" src="star.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are my images: [White Star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfswl.png) [Yellow Star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKvQ.png)

Comment: Try with `$(".stars").on("click",".n",function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `jquery.on` for this. Please see below working code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".stars").on("click", ".n", function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKvQ.png');
    $(this).removeClass("n");
    $(this).addClass("y");
  });
  $(".stars").on("click", ".y", function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfswl.png');
    $(this).removeClass("y");
    $(this).addClass("n");
  });
});
```

```css
div#rating {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>


<div class="stars">
  <img class="y" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKvQ.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  <img class="y" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKvQ.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  <img class="n" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfswl.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  <img class="n" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfswl.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  <img class="n" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfswl.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```